# Trying to get an older Sony Vaio to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, sony-vaio

I've got an older Vaio, model VGN-S550P.  I'm trying to load it up with a new OS from USB, but I'm having no luck getting to to recognize the flash drive.  It doesn't appear in the boot menu or BIOS, and there's not option for booting from USB therein.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be most thankful.

Cheers,

Dennis

Comment: Did you try F11,Esc or F10 at boot to get a boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is a common one with older motherboards. Only until the last 5-7 years did motherboards allow you to install an operating system from USB. Just to be clear, this issue is a motherboard issue 100%.

According to Sony's Website. Your computer is around 10 years old. It's very doubtful your motherboard will allow such functionality. But without the exact model of the motherboard, it would be impossible to say. The fact that you mention it's not in the bios setting, should give your answer right there.

My guess is you probably assumed loading an operating system via usb was always "a thing". But USB flash drives are actually a very recent technology

Solution: You'll need to install the OS via CD/DVD rom.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured the USB is a bootable drive? What tool did you use to create the USB?

I have used [Rufus](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjP5t_4gLLhAhULXK0KHTv6A70QFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frufus.ie%2F&usg=AOvVaw360qlGZbGE3DcSah5A5ITM) or [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) with success in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Sony Vaio VGN-FS640, whose optical drive is no longer working properly. So, I cannot install an OS using the optical drive, neither is there a way to boot from USB, since this option does not exist on this old laptop. So, the only way to install an OS (GNU-Linux would be the best choice), I have to check out on the internet how to boot via PXE (network boot) and install from a PXE server (another computer that hosts the .iso image.
I haven't yet taken the time to investigate how to make a PXE server and how to boot that laptop from it, but this is the only way.
The only time I booted it via PXE was using a crossover cable, booting from the optical drive of another PC, which had an older Slax (live Linux distro) that had the PXE enabled, so you could use that computer as a server to boot other PCs directly from its optical drive. But since Slax does not have an installer, I cannot use it to install an OS on that laptop. I can only use it as some sort of "terminal" connected to that host / server PC. But this is my only experience with booting from PXE (so far).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118324)